# Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding BasicHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http]

Tags: http, wcf, iis, https

I am facing the above issue when I uploaded my wcf service on IIS

the error is:

> Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the
> endpoint with binding BasicHttpBinding. Registered base address
> schemes are [http].

my web config look like the followin

```
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                    maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
```

And this is how I am calling the wcf service

```
http://service/appname/service.svc
```

what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem indicates that there is a problem with your configuration file. You may have configured HTTPS features in the configuration file. Please make sure that there is no HTTPS configuration in the configuration file.

You can check serviceMetadata first to make sure to use httpGetEnabled:

```
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
```

Instead of:

```
<serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
```

If the problem still exists, please post your entire web.config.

Comment: How could we configure web.config so that it can handle https?